# how to pass two variable with values in windo.location.href and access them in codeigniter view page

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Hi I want to pass variable which contain some values  by using `window.location.href` so how to pass  and  access those two variables in view page which will be call by method, actually  I am getting some error .

```
<script>

var v1="1";
var v2="2";


 window.location.href = "<?=base_url('controller/method/') ?>"+v1+" ";

</script>
```

Comment: What's the error? You also only appear to be appending one of the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<script>
var v1="1";
var v2="2";
window.location.href = "<?= base_url('controller/method/') ?>"+v1+"/"+v2;
</script>
```

In your controller you can access them via:

```
<?php
$v1 = $this->uri->segment(3);
$v2 = $this->uri->segment(4);
?>
```

Then you can pass them to your view.

More info here: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html#class-reference

Comment: thanks it is working fine , so how to hide two id which I am able to see in url ,it should get pass but should not visible to anyone

Comment: If you want to pass something, but don't want to show it in the URL, than rather use a POST.

Comment: can you please tell me how to do this

Comment: Try googling 'jquery ajax'

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

```
<script>
var v1="1";
var v2="2";

 window.location.href = "<?=base_url('controller/testing/') ?>"+ v1+"/"+v2;
</script>
```

Your controller's method (here `testing`) should be like this :

```
public function testing($param1, $param2)
{
     echo $param1; /*output 1*/
     echo $param2; /*output 2*/
}
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#passing-uri-segments-to-your-methods